# Client failing to connect on HornetQ server

Tags: jms, spring-jms, hornetq

I have a spring-boot application acting as a HornetQ server and ~10 client applications sending and receiving messages without any problem.
But there's one specific client that refuses to connect with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: HQ119014: Timed out waiting for response when sending packet 30
  at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
  at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.executeLocal(JmsTemplate.java:987)
  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.sendAndReceive(JmsTemplate.java:923)
  at coral.rapidreconciler.agent.jms.AgentConnectionJms.connectToValc(AgentConnectionJms.java:52)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
  at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: HQ119014: Timed out waiting for response when sending packet 30
  at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:390)
  at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionInternal(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:891)
  at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionInternal(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:800)
  at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSession(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:337)
  at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnection.authorize(HornetQConnection.java:719)
  at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:762)
  at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:112)
  at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:107)
  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.executeLocal(JmsTemplate.java:976)
  ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hornetq.api.core.HornetQConnectionTimedOutException: HQ119014: Timed out waiting for response when sending packet 30
  ... 24 common frames omitted
```

On the server this line appears on the log:

```
2016-01-29 16:22:19.389  WARN 4764 --- [re-check-thread] org.hornetq.core.client                  : HQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: HQ119014: Did not receive data from /xx.xxx.xx.xxx:61350. It is likely the client has exited or crashed without closing its connection, or the network between the server and client has failed. You also might have configured connection-ttl and client-failure-check-period incorrectly. Please check user manual for more information. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
```

Any directions to discover what's wrong with this client? Firewall, proxy, network, resources, version?

Answer (score 0):

Chances a networking problem then, some of the things I would do:

1) Ping HornetQ from the problematic client and ping the client from the HornetQ server.  If you can't ping from either side, it's likely a configuration issue, such as bad netmask or gateway or something.  Traceroute/tracert is your friend her.

2) From the problematic client, try to telnet to Hornetq server on port 5446 (assuming you're using the default).  If the port open, type some garbage characters and see if you get a response, even with garbage getting some sort of response should indicate that the client can reach the server.

3) Turn on a bunch more logging, depending on how its configured or whether you're running in JBoss or some other app server might change what specifically you want to do, can't tell you without knowing the details of your implementation.  Client-side debug logging should be your friend.

Comment: Telnet works (this is the intriguing part) and log is on trace, but I can't find anything useful there.

Comment: Any firewall or something sniffing traffic?  Is client who can't get to JBoss/Hornetq in a different subnet than the clients who can connect?  Could there be something in between that's filtering that specific traffic based on content?  It might be that telnet to port 5446 doesn't trigger anything because you haven't sent data in the right protocol, but an actual Hornetq message does.  The fact that your not seeing anything in the JBoss log means its not even getting it, might be worth trying a netstat -a on the OS.  You also might check what JBoss is listening to, might be a specific subnet.